# How to copy entire folder and subfolder from remote sever to local machine using PuTTY psftp

Tags: scripting, sftp, putty

I am doing an automation to copy folder and subfolder from remote server to local machine i know the command to copy all the files inside folder

```
mget *.extension
```

But I want to know is there any command in psftp to copy folder and subfolder recursively to my local machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use scp. (example) `scp -r user@remote:/path/to/folder /home/user/Desktop/`

Comment: for using scp do i need to install any software?

Comment: I think it comes included on *nix machines. Not sure about windows though.

Comment: Stumbled on this thread. If you're on windows, install PuTTY and use the PSCP.exe utility through the command line.

Answer (score 4):

To copy files recursively with the `psftp`, use the `get` or the `mget` with the `-r` (recurse) switch.

For example:

```
get -r /remote/path C:\local\path
```

See:

- [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-get](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-get)
- [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mgetput](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter6.html#psftp-cmd-mgetput)

---

Or as @jbarnett suggested, you can use the SCP. PuTTY has an SCP client too, the `pscp`:

```
pscp -r user@example.com:/remote/path C:\local\path
```

See [https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp](https://the.earth.li/%7Esgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter5.html#pscp)